# Hosting / embed a Windows service to a WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, windows-services

I am new to C#. I have done Android programming before.

I need to write a program with one control panel only and in the background the program writes to a database per 30s. The UI is updated by reading from the database per second.

I am planning to use a windows service for the background update of the database, along with multiple asynchronous threads.

Question:
1) As asynchronous threads runs in the background only, is it necessary to use a service on it also? Is it better to avoid kicking off these asynchronous threads at UI thread?

2) In Android programming, I could simply create a new service/ asynchronous threads class inside the project and start the service/ thread programming from there. In C# (I'm on visual studio 2010, using WPF as the control panel), it seems I need to start a new window service project, code from there, and them import it into the WPF project? Is that true?

3) And is the MainWindow.xaml.cs the main/ UI thread?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services and threads are two different concepts in .net a thread is a lightweight object that is scheduled in the context of the same process, a service has a defined interface and usually runs in the context of a different process.

In order to keep the ui responsive the usual practice is to create another thread to perform long running operations, note that if a background thread needs to communicate with the ui, switching to the ui thread is required before interacting with ui elements.

So your database update code could be run as a task on another thread in your ui application or via WCF to a windows service which would be responsible for all database activity.

Lastly the wpf application and the windows service can be part of the same solution but both produce executables and the windows service must be installed with the service installer. You would still need to use WCF to communicate between ui and windows service.

Unless required,I would consider doing the database io in a separate thread Task<> and avoid a windows service unless the io will continue when the UI is not present.